# how to pass ServletRequest to pojo that does i/o in graphql-java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I need to pass a servlet attribute value to the Query object on a per request basis.  I have this much working, but how can I get the real Query object from the qt variable?

```
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GraphQLSchema schema = getSchemaProvider().getSchema();
    //schema.transform(c -> {});
    GraphQLObjectType t = schema.getQueryType();
    String rootLib = (String) req.getAttribute("ROOTLIB");
    super.service(req, res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

extend DefaultQLSchemaProvider and override the getSchema(request:HttpServletRequest):GraphQLSchema method.
Then override the GraphQLEndpoint ctor and create the schemaProvider when calling super(GrapQLProvider, ...) ctor.